# SQLiteDataAdapter Fill exception

Tags: c#, exception, ado.net, oledb

I'm trying to use the OleDb CSV parser to load some data from a CSV file and insert it into a SQLite database, but I get an exception with the `OleDbAdapter.Fill` method and it's frustrating:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.ConstraintException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to
>   enable constraints. One or more rows
>   contain values violating non-null,
>   unique, or foreign-key constraints.

Here is the source code:

```
public void InsertData(String csvFileName, String tableName)
{
    String dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(csvFileName);
    String name = Path.GetFileName(csvFileName);

    using (OleDbConnection conn =
        new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
        dir + @";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"""))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + name, conn))
        {
            QuoteDataSet ds = new QuoteDataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, tableName); // <-- Exception here
            InsertData(ds, tableName); // <-- Inserts the data into the my SQLite db
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase target = new SQLiteDatabase(); 
        string csvFileName = "D:\\Innovations\\Finch\\dev\\DataFeed\\YahooTagsInfo.csv"; 
        string tableName = "Tags";
        target.InsertData(csvFileName, tableName);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The "YahooTagsInfo.csv" file looks like this:

```
tagId,tagName,description,colName,dataType,realTime
1,s,Symbol,symbol,VARCHAR,FALSE
2,c8,After Hours Change,afterhours,DOUBLE,TRUE
3,g3,Annualized Gain,annualizedGain,DOUBLE,FALSE
4,a,Ask,ask,DOUBLE,FALSE
5,a5,Ask Size,askSize,DOUBLE,FALSE
6,a2,Average Daily Volume,avgDailyVolume,DOUBLE,FALSE
7,b,Bid,bid,DOUBLE,FALSE
8,b6,Bid Size,bidSize,DOUBLE,FALSE
9,b4,Book Value,bookValue,DOUBLE,FALSE
```

I've tried the following:

1. Removing the first line in the CSV file so it doesn't confuse it for real data.
2. Changing the TRUE/FALSE realTime flag to 1/0.
3. I've tried 1 and 2 together (i.e. removed the first line and changed the flag).

None of these things helped...

One constraint is that the tagId is supposed to be unique.  Here is what the table look like in design view:

[image: Tags Table]

Can anybody help me figure out what is the problem here?

**Update:**
I changed the HDR property from `HDR=No` to `HDR=Yes` and now it doesn't give me an exception:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + @";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited""");
```

I assumed that if `HDR=No` and I removed the header (i.e. first line), then it should work... strangely it didn't work. In any case, now I'm no longer getting the exception.

The new problem arose here: [SQLiteDataAdapter Update method returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711021/sqlitedataadapter-update-method-returning-0)

Comment: Maybe it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711021/sqlitedataadapter-update-method-returning-0?

Comment: @John I split it into a separate question because I don't want to clutter this one too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: IMO emplacing keys and constraints on a transport structure such as your dataset is a bad idea.

Use a transaction and let the target db throw if it wants.

Second: have you examined the ds to ensure the csv is getting loaded? VS has a dataset debug visualizer built in - simply set a break point after the ds is loaded and hover over the variable name, click the little down-arrow and select the appropriate visualizer.

Third: I don't think that you are generating an insert command. Just before you call update, check the InsertCommand.CommandText..

```
var cmdText = sqliteAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText;
```

I think you will find that it is empty.

This is the source of the SQLiteDataAdapter ctor that ultimately gets called. Note that no command builder is employed. You need to explicitly set the InserCommand property on the SQLiteDataAdapter, perhaps by using a SQLiteCommandBuilder?

```
public SQLiteDataAdapter(string commandText, SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    this.SelectCommand = new SQLiteCommand(commandText, connection);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sky, thanks for the answer... I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say that I'm placing keys and constraints on my dataset? The dataset was automatically generated based on the table showed in the picture. So the CSV was getting loaded, and now I'm loading 83 rows from the CSV file, but when I try to update the db it's not updating any rows (i.e. sqliteAdapter.Update(...) returns 0).

Comment: I've already figured out the problem with this question, but I'll give you the points since you're the only one answering it :)... additionally, I'm interested in your comment about the keys and constraints.  FYI: I wrote another question with that specific problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711021/sqlitedataadapter-update-method-returning-0-c

Comment: @lirik - updated answer with an obvious possiblity that I missed earlier. Also - the other question should be closed, it is the same.

Comment: I forwarded the parts that were the same to the other question. So what were you saying about the constraints and the keys?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the HDR property from `HDR=No` to `HDR=Yes` and *now it doesn't give me an exception anymore*... here is what the connection string looks like:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + @";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited""");
```

I assumed that if `HDR=No` and I removed the header (i.e. first line), then it should work... the only way to get rid of the exception if `HDR=No` is if I remove the constraints by calling `ds.EnforceConstraints = false;`

In any case, now I'm no longer getting the exception. If anybody can explain why this is happening, then please do tell.