# How to Insert and Update datagrid row in database table

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, advanceddatagrid

I am developing C# without using any framework.until now i successfully performed following task on Datagrid.

```
1.Displaying data in Data-grid by binding with database table
2.Getting the selected row data from Data-grid based on primary key
```

Here is my variable declaration :

```
SQLiteDataAdapter adap;
SQLiteCommandBuilder cmdbl;
DataSet ds;
String Query;
DataTable dt;
```

Here is code for displaying data in Data-grid :

```
try
{
    Query = "Select * from Items";
    adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds, "Items");
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dtgitems.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    dtgitems.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    ds.Dispose();
    adap.Dispose();
    dt.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

It is working fine
and here is my code for updating that data-grid

```
try
 {
     cmdbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adap);
     adap.Update(ds, "Items");
    // ds.Tables[0].Clear();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
```

it is not working .Does anyone knows how i can accomplish this update functionality in data-grid ? .Please help me to correct this code for update opreation .Thanks

Comment: `DataContext`? `ItemsSource`? Winforms?

Comment: Asp.net?? or winforms???

Answer (score 0):

Although I would work with an ObservableCollection, you can update your datagrid items with the following code:

```
dtgItems.Items.Refresh();
```

Do this after you updated the source.
I should use it in your code like this:
You should accept the changes so your database gets updated.

```
try
{
    cmdbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adap);
    adap.Update(ds, "Items");
    ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
    dtgItems.Items.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Where to add this command ?: dtgItems.Items.Refresh(); in update code like this :  try
            {
                cmdbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adap);
                adap.Update(ds, "Items");
                dtgitems.Items.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("updated");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

Comment: still not working with dtgItems.Items.Refresh(); command..it is not updating database ....

Comment: code is executed till this line adap.Update(ds, "Items");  after that line are skipped

Comment: Your question was to update the datagrid, not the database. Consider changing your question then.

Comment: Check the return value of adap.update; It should say how many rows that are succesfully updated.

Comment: on debugging by placing break point ...It  does not show any return value .....it just shows :Delete command -Null, Insert command-Null,Update Command -null,Select command -null ...and other details

Comment: Yes, but when you set a breakpoint on the line "adap.Update..." the method is not yet executed. For testing purpose do something like this: var returnValue = adap.Update(ds, "Items"); and set breakpoint on dtgItems.Items.refresh. When it breaks, check the value of returnValue

Comment: returnValue=0 in while debugging in watch window

Comment: if i try this code with updated data grid the Message box does not appear ....other wise message box is shown ....this means that update function is not updating my table  ....code is  :           try
            {
                cmdbl = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adap);
                var returnValue = adap.Update(ds, "Items");
                dtgitems.Items.Refresh();
                MessageBox.Show("updated");
            }

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711021/sqlitedataadapter-update-method-returning-0

Comment: still same behavior  ...it is not updating in db ..execution still not progress after this command ...without any compiler message ..adap.Update(ds, "Items");  ....please Help

Comment: It is off topic,, you should ask new question. I have no experience with SqlLiteCommandBuilder

Comment: No.... same code(with few keyword difference) with same db is working in win-from with data grid view ...But in wpf it is not working with data-grid ....so SqlLiteCommandBuilder is working correctly in win-form