# SQLite create DB table from xml (xsd)

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite, xsd, sqlxml

I have xml (xsd) file. I need create db table in SQLite db, and load data from XML to this table (in C# application).

I try to use this code:

```
string ConnectionStr = "Data Source=mydb.sqlite;Version=3; New=True; Compress = True;";
NDbUnit.Core.INDbUnitTest Database = new NDbUnit.Core.SqlLite.SqlLiteDbUnitTest(ConnectionStr);
Database.ReadXmlSchema("AS_ACTSTAT.xsd");
Database.ReadXml("AS_ACTSTAT.xml");
Database.PerformDbOperation(NDbUnit.Core.DbOperationFlag.CleanInsertIdentity);
```

But I have this error (read xml schema):

> SqlDbCommandBuilder.CreateSelectCommand(DataSet, string) failed for
>   tableName = 'ActualStatus'

Schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:usch="http://www.unisoftware.ru/schematron-extensions" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="ActualStatuses" sql:is-constant="true" >
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>sostav</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ActualStatus" maxOccurs="unbounded" sql:relation="AS_ACTSTAT">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>status</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="ACTSTATID" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>key</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                    <xs:totalDigits value="10"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                        <xs:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                            <xs:annotation>
                                <xs:documentation>name
0 – non actual
1 – actual
</xs:documentation>
                            </xs:annotation>
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                                    <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

ps Also I try use SqlXml 4.0 from Microsoft (it works great with MS SQL 2008), but can't find OLEDB driver for SQLite.

Any idea? I need something like SqlXml 4.0 fo SQlite, because i dont know structure of xml file previously.

Comment: You should be able to get a more detailed error for this. The table may even exist.

Comment: No, in db this table missing, problem when start read xsd in

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLiteDataAdapter Fill exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710751/sqlitedataadapter-fill-exception)